# Specify toolchainVersion and productFlavors in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to setup Android Studio and Gradle to build our android app with native code.

Due to our dependencies we are using GCC 4.8 to compile for `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`.
I tried specifying toolchain and abi in the following way:

```
model {
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "my_native"
        toolchain = "gcc"
        toolchainVersion = "4.8"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11 -fexceptions -frtti")
        stl = "gnustl_static"
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("x86")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifying the toolchain works fine, but Gradle ignores the abiFilters when syncing and creates Tasks for all ABIs which fails as GCC 4.8 is not supported for `arm64-v8a` in the latest version of the NDK (r10e I believe).

I am using version `0.4.0` of the `gradle-experimental` plugin and version `2.8` of the Gradle wrapper. Android Studio is version `1.5.0` (latest stable).

How do I correctly specify the toolchain to use with a set of ABIs?

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar question and found [this article](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) helpful.

If you build one APK for 3 architectures at once, you should create another one item in the module `android.productFlavors` in app build.gradle script:

```
android.productFlavors {
    create("abi3") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
    }
}
```

Now syncing the project with Gradle files will result in Android Studio automatically creating another two Build Variants (see "Build Variants" toolbar): abi3Debug and abi3Release. So you can use one of these variants to build your project.
And now I guess you're using the default build variant which builds your project with `APP_ABI=all` key.

Comment: I have no desire to create a fat APK and your answer does not touch on specifying toolchain.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that the toolchain version had been specified in the android.ndk module: `toolchainVersion = "4.8"`. But anyway that will be no use in case you don't create fat APK. I'll investigate the issue further. If you have any solution I'll be grateful for it.